# jquery animate or ease scroll left increment

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#right_arrow").click(function(e) {
        var scrollleftvar = $(window).scrollLeft();
        e.preventDefault()
        $("body").scrollLeft(scrollleftvar + 50);
    });
});
```

Hi, Im trying to animate or ease the incremental scroll eleft triggered above, but struggling a little, any help would be really appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the `.animate()`-function:

```
$('body').animate( { scrollLeft: '+=50' }, 1000, 'easeOutQuad' );
```

- The first parameter sets the value you want to animate. You can use something like `+=value` or `-=value` to animate from the current value (like an offset).
- The second parameter is the time the animation is running.
- And the third is the easing, if you're using an easing plug-in.

See the [jQuery-Docs: ".animate()"](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more informations.